# How to get the Author ID of the product in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am now developing a magento website, at a first glance at the task I found getting the ID of the author of the product seems to be hard for me as I am a newbie in magento. Can anyone help me on how to get the Id of the user that created the product in product view? cause i want to show the information of the author of the product in the product view. Hope someone can help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per default magento setup only admin can create a product in admin end. Is there any customized section where users are creating product. If so, add an attribute author_id to product and in that customized code save the current logged in customers id while saving the product.

For more help need to go through your current structure. Can you procide some code snippet or a demo url

Comment: Thank you for your response sandeep. Now its clear to me that I should create a method inside the model of the module that i bought to get the customer ID that created the product. Thanks so much.